# How to change Stepper line color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, stepper

I would like to customize my Stepper in my flutter App.
I changed the color of the background number and the Stepper background with Theme(ThemeData), but i would like to change the color and the height of the little line between every steps.

How is it possible ?
Is there a way to extends Stepper class, and change the Widget "Widget _buildHorizontal" ?
I saw that's the only way to change line height & color.
But how can i extends it ?

I tried all the possible color from ThemeData.

[The result i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewCbR.png)

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet that you've tried so far and image that you are trying to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Flutter does not have a way to change the color of Stepper Line because the color of stepper line is static.

[image of source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnhjd.png)

You can create a custom stepper:

https://nakib.medium.com/making-a-custom-number-stepper-in-flutter-e8bdde04b3f
https://medium.com/fabcoding/create-an-icon-stepper-view-in-flutter-3fb53fe2e3bc

or use a package like:
[easy_stepper](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_stepper),
[im_stepper](https://pub.dev/packages/im_stepper),
[cupertino_stepper](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_stepper)